# Release build but debugging enabled

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to export an Android app. I've selected "Release | ARM".

It creates a bundle and lists it in the archives section but there's a warning next to it that says, "Archive built with debugging enabled".

How can that be, given that it's a release build?

How do switch off debugging?

Comment: open the Project options dialog, go the Debug tab, and disable it for the Release configuration

Comment: For some reason, the check box for "Enable developer instrumentation" was ghosted. I had to remove `<DebugType>full</DebugType>` from the project file. I wonder why that's in a release build. Nonetheless, the warning is still there. This is VS on Mac. I can't see a debug tab.

Comment: Sorry, that was iOS.  In Android it's under Compiler

Comment: This is strange. There's a drop down and it says, "Debug Information: None" and the only symbol defined is "TRACE".

Comment: Oh, my first action worked. It was showing a new "Duplicate version" warning after that. :)

Answer (score 102):

I'm using Visual Studio for Mac and came across this same "Archive built with debugging enabled" warning after creating an archive of the Android project.

To fix this, do the following:

1. Go into the Android project options (double-click on the Android project).
2. Select the Compiler options.
3. In the "Debug information" drop-down menu, select `None` (mine had the `Portable` option selected). Do this configuration for the Release build (the "Configuration" drop-down menu at the top says `Release (Active)`).
4. Click on the Android Build options and take a look at the "Debugging Options". The `Enable developer instrumentation (debugging and profiling)`setting should be greyed out (and the checkbox should be unchecked). The setting is greyed out because of what was done in step 3.
5. Publish the project.

So the problem was that by default the "Debug Information" wasn't set to `None`.

Comment: Step 3 fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Step 3 fixed it for me as well. Thanks!

Comment: I was also facing same issue on Visual Studio for Mac. Option 3 made it.

Comment: Select None worked for me on Visual Studio for Mac. Thanks!

Comment: @karlingen do you know how to fix the same issue for the ios App (ipa)

Comment: @Swathy Sorry mate.